# Embed backbone response into underscore template within Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using backbone.js for a rails project I've got on the side. I'm embedding templates in the rails views using something like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="this-is-the-id">
    ... template goes here ...

    ... the line below this is where my error's coming from ...

    <%% _(<%= aNumber %>.times(function(){ console.log('hi'); });) %>
</script>
```

I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. If I replace `<%= aNumber %>` with an integer, it works as expected. Also, if I `console.log(<%%= aNumber %>)`, it logs the correct number.

Does anybody know how I can accomplish something like this? I know that's kind of a sloppy way to organize my code, but this is just a quick little hack I'm putting together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to wrap `aNumber` within the escaping `<%%=` and `%>`, and that fixed it for me.

Comment: You might want to create this as an answer and accept it, so that it doesn't show up in unanswered lists anymore.